# copy files from drop location to different file location

Tags: msbuild, build-process

I have build definition for a project which outputs some MSI files and zip files with assembly version folder name to Drop folder. eg: 1.0.0.0 folder contains MSI and zip files.
Now my requirement at final step is to copy only MSI files from above drop folder and copy to different file location as part of build process.

How can i achieve this using build process template or post build script?

Thanks

Comment: How would these locations be used? Are you trying to put the build outputs in two different locations? Why not just make a copy?

Comment: @John, even copy also looks fine. Can you help me how can i specify the location and copy the files to different location in xaml template or post build script.Thanks.

Comment: First, edit your question to state what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: As John mentioned, state why you want to create another copy of the MSI? That would help answer the question better.